# $W(t)$ is Brownian motion. Then $E\{\exp[\int_0^t u\Delta(s)dW(s)-1/2\int_0^t(u\Delta(s))^2ds]\}=1$

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

$W(t)$ is Brownian motion. Then $E\{\exp[\int_0^t u\Delta(s)dW(s)-1/2\int_0^t(u\Delta(s))^2ds]\}=1$ where $\Delta(s)$ is some appropriate function to make sense above expectation value for some $u$ over small interval.

$\textbf{Q:}$ Why $E\{\exp[\int_0^t u\Delta(s)dW(s)-1/2\int_0^t(u\Delta(s))^2ds]\}=1$ holds even for $\Delta(s)$ non-deterministic? (If $\Delta(s)$ is deterministic, then it is easy to see this holds by martingale property of generalized geometric Brownian motion.)

Ref. S. Shreve Stochastic Calculus for Finance Vol. II chapter 4, equation 4.4.31 and comment right after the proof of Theorem 4.4.9

Comment: If $\Delta(s)$ is an adapted process that suitably decays, then $Y_t=\int_0^t\Delta(s)dW(s)$ is a martingale. In general, the exponential $Z_t=\exp(uY_t-\frac{u^2}{2}[Y_t])$ is then again a martingale, which only uses that $Y_t$ is a martingale. For a reference to this, look up the Doléans-Dade exponential. When $t=0$, this quantitiy is clearly one, so we have that $\mathbb{E} Z_t=\mathbb{E} Z_0=1$, which shows what you want.

Comment: @PaxKivimae Thanks. I think the whole point is to realize that Ito integral is martingale under assumption that $\Delta(s)$ is adapted and decays.

Comment: Yes, this is generally the subject of Ito calculus. More often, the integral of $\int_0^t\Delta(s)dW(s)$ is only a local martingale, but if, for example, $\Delta(s)$ is of compact-support, then all conditions is satified. This type of stuff should hopefully be covered in Chapter 4 of your book.